# Spring Injection of JPA Repository bean is not working - NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to inject JPA repositories managed and implemented by Spring to a service class. But in the runtime program throws NPE on line 39.

Here is my service class:

```java
@Service
public class RegistrationFormProcessor {

    private ContractorRepository contractorRepository;
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationFormProcessor(ContractorRepository contractorRepository, AddressRepository addressRepository, UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.contractorRepository = contractorRepository;
        this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public User prepareUser(RegistrationForm registrationForm) {
        Address address = new Address(
                registrationForm.getCountry(),
                registrationForm.getCity(),
                registrationForm.getStreet(),
                registrationForm.getZipCode(),
                registrationForm.getProperty()
        );
        Address savedAddress = addressRepository.save(address); // line 39

        Contractor userCompany = new Contractor(
                registrationForm.getCompanyName(),
                registrationForm.getShortName(),
                savedAddress,
                registrationForm.getNip(),
                registrationForm.getRegon(),
                registrationForm.getPhone(),
                registrationForm.getEmail(),
                registrationForm.getWebsite()
        );
        Contractor savedUserCompany = contractorRepository.save(userCompany); // line 51

        User user = new User(
                registrationForm.getFirstName(),
                registrationForm.getLastName(),
                registrationForm.getLastName(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(registrationForm.getPassword()),
                "ROLE_USER",
                true,
                savedUserCompany
        );
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        savedUserCompany.setOwner(savedUser);
        contractorRepository.save(savedUserCompany);

        return savedUser;
    }
```

AddressRepository and other fields are autowired with interfaces that are managed by Spring which is implementing all methods automatically.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository <Address, Long> {}
```

In my case an instance of RegistrationFormProcessor is an instance managed by Spring (at least I hope it is). RegistrationFormProcessor is annotated `@Service` and is injected in one of controller class. There it is used and program is throwing mentioned exception. Below a controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public RegistrationController(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String registerForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("registrationForm", new RegistrationForm());
        return "register/registration";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm form, @Autowired RegistrationFormProcessor registrationFormProcessor) {
        registrationFormProcessor.prepareUser(form);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

If line 39 would be removed program would thow NPE on line 51 (and so on if `userRepository.save(user)` is called). In these lines should be used repository with methods like `save()` implemented by Spring-data automatically.

I have similar injections (also in constructors) in controller classes and there everything is working fine.

What I'm doing wrong? Why in service class Spring does not inject these dependencies and fields are null? I tried to set a breakpoint and debug - confirmed that fields are `null` .  As I said above in other classes which are annotated as `@Controller` same fields also injected in constructor aren't nulls and all is working fine.

Tried to annotate interface AddresRepository as `@Repository` but it is not working. On the other hand it is not necessary for sure for Spring - Spring is implementing methods correctly as checked in controllers.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: add `@Repository` above `public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository <Address, Long> {}`

Comment: Is the constructor invoked with a non-null repository?  What is invoking `RegistrationFormProcessor#prepareUser(...) ?  Is that class uses a spring managed instance of `RegistrationFormProcessor`?

Comment: Have you put a debug breakpoint on that line and checked the values of your fields?

Comment: What is line 39/51? Did you use the spring bean of the class or did you instantiate it yourself?

Comment: @AndrewS question edited

Comment: Can you show your Spring context's config?

Comment: The reason can be due to failing to save entities to DB. Can you show code for Address and Contractor entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by moving RegistrationFormProcessor injection in controller from injection in controller method as a parameter to declaration as field and injection in controller field.

Before

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public RegistrationController(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm form, @Autowired RegistrationFormProcessor registrationFormProcessor) {
        registrationFormProcessor.prepareUser(form); // throws NPE - not working
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

After:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final RegistrationFormProcessor registrationFormProcessor;

    public RegistrationController(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, RegistrationFormProcessor registrationFormProcessor) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.registrationFormProcessor = registrationFormProcessor;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm form) {
        registrationFormProcessor.prepareUser(form); //working fine
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

But can't explain why...

Comment: There are defined ways to do injection with spring. Injecting via the business method - as the case in your question - is not one of them. See e.g. https://medium.com/@ilyailin7777/all-dependency-injection-types-spring-336da7baf51b

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove @Autowired annotation and add final keyword to repository definitions like below:

```
private final ContractorRepository contractorRepository;
private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public RegistrationFormProcessor(ContractorRepository contractorRepository, AddressRepository addressRepository, UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.contractorRepository = contractorRepository;
    this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}
```

Comment: Tried but nothing changed. Also IntelliJ shows in both cases that beans are correctly wired.

Comment: Okay, so there must be an issue related to database connection. It would be helpful if you can share full error log.

Comment: @azzabi-haythem Hi, you edited my answer but you tried to change "remove" to "add" however I meant to remove and you can see I removed autowired annotation in the code sample. So, I reverted back to the original answer.

Comment: @HalilKalkan ok :)

Comment: add @Autowired on constructor

Answer (score 0):

You should try add `final` keyword for your repositories for injecting, like that:

```
private final ContractorRepository contractorRepository;
private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
...
```

Comment: May be there is an issue with your context within' service class. Do you use Spring Boot? What version?